# uwamp apache error - Failed to kill process

Tags: php, apache, uwamp

I have UwAmp 3.1.0, sometimes the Apache has trouble to close properly regardless the PHP version installed.

Logs file are telling me

```
[Thu Mar 03 12:50:58.385893 2016] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 544:tid 236] AH02538: Child: Parent process exited abruptly. Child process is ending
```

here the configuration file for apache http://pastebin.com/iJZmdS3A

The problem comes with Windows 7 and windows 10

[image: error]

thanks

Comment: This error occurs since I know UwAmp at its version 1.x.x. To me, this is because UwAmp try to kill some others processes in addition to Apache when stopping Apache. But there's a trouble with the PID UwAmp wants to kill, and these PID are actually internal processes you have no rights to kill. The solution could be fixing the "PID to kill list" inside UwAmp software. On the site http://www.uwamp.com/en/ there's a "uBugTrack" tab, but I'm not able to find any public bug tracker opened for UwAmp bugs.

Comment: Still a bug no one seems to care about. It's interesting though, because sometimes it works OK, but when it runs for a few hours, it can't kill it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem of computer.
I work with Uwamp "installed" on usb key with several computers.
This error occurs only with one each time i close the application.

Answer (score 0):

That's a product bug, but to be able to kill it and continue the work just look for cmd, open it as admin, run the tasklist command, look for the name of the process and kill it.

```
taskkill /IM name_of_process.exe /F
```

Answer (score -1):

https://www.uwamp.com/en/?page=download
Prerequisites IMPORTANT!!

Before use UwAmp you must install Visual C++ Redistributable x86 version vc_redist.x86.exe. This is a PHP requirement.

You can install multiple versions of Redistributable for Visual Studio and you can install both version x86 and x64. UwAmp use x86 version to keep compatibility with older PHP version.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35418265)